# Como remover um campo já adicionado a um 'FormData'?

Tags: javascript, ajax, formdata

O código a seguir insere arquivos vindos de um campo `file`, em um `FormData`:

```javascript
var filedata = event.target; // FileList object
var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, file;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    file = filedata.files[i];
    // ...

    // Aqui adiciono o campo ao FormData
    formData.append('img_upload_'+(countFiles++), file);
}
```

## Pergunta

É possível remover em determinado momento, um arquivo/campo previamente adicionado ao `FormData`, ou tenho que criar uma nova instância, e mandar o usuário adicionar todos os arquivos novamente?

O método acima é executado toda vez acontece uma modificação (evento `onchange`) em um campo `input` do tipo `file`. Ao final, `formData` será enviado por AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `FormData` só possui método `append`. Porém, nesse cenário seria melhor não populá-lo no `onchange`. Se necessário, você pode manter uma array com os objetos `File`, e a array pode ser manipulada quando preciso. Deixe para criar/popular o `FormData` somente no final, logo antes da requisição AJAX.

Comment: Sim, já tinha começado a fazer modificações para funcionar desta forma. Logo posto se funcionou ou não.

Comment: Sim, depois de muito esforço com Javascript e algumas horas de debug, consegui fazer funcionar. Adicionei suporte pra drag & drop também.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! @CalebeOliveira